# Что значит "предварительно компилируемый" язык программирования?

Tags: 1с

Искал инфу по языку программирования 1С, и там такая строчка была. Гугл, кроме ещё большего смятения, ничего не дал - "предварительно компилируемый" пишут не только для 1С. Так что же это всё таки такое?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Предварительно компилируемый язык** (в отличие от языков **динамического разбора**) - это тот язык, программы на котором надо сначала **компилировать**, потом **выполнять** (например C, C++). Результатом компиляции здесь будет машинный код.

К ним же относятся и такие интерпретируемые (скриптовые) языки, как Python, Perl, Ruby, ибо компиляция (так называемая "прекомпиляция", или "компиляция на лету") у них происходит автоматически перед выполнением программы самим интерпретатором. Здесь результатом предкомпиляции будет "байт-код".

**Языки динамического разбора**, напротив же, считывают инструкции из файла программы минимально требующимися блоками, и исполняют эти блоки, не читая дальнейший код. Например shell (sh и прочая), command.com.

Comment: Во! Огромное спасибо:) В принципе так и думал:)

Comment: В данном ответе смешиваются понятия AOT (ahead of time) компиляции (C, C++, Go, Rust и т.д.) и JIT (just in time). Поэтому утверждение, что Python, Ruby, Perl и т.д. стоят в одном ряду с AOT компилируемыми языками не верно.

Answer (score 3):

Про 1C ничего не знаю, но во всяких C/C++ есть такая штука, как [precompiled headers](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8). Заголовочные файлы заранее компилятся в промежуточный формат, чтобы при компиляции сэкономить время. Это, конечно, догадка «пальцем в небо», но, возможно, речь про это?

Comment: Как вариант. Тоже про это думал.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит что перед запуском программы которую ты написал, она переводиться в машинный код

Comment: А чем, в таком случае, отличается обычная компиляция от этой? Или я не совсем правильно понял? К примеру по шагам при компиляции (урезанно). Пишем код, компилируем (код переводится в машинный, создается экзешник, к примеру), запускаем прогу, работает. А тут - написал код, сохранил (создалось приложение, ГРУБО ГОВОРЯ пусть тоже .exe), запустил, он переводит код в машинный (компилируется?) и работает? Так?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что это компиляция в байт-код. Касаемо языка 1С - насколько я знаю, это они купили лицензию VBA

Answer (score 0):

В процессе разработки платформа 1С производит предварительную компиляцию в Байт - код. 
Это еще не машшинный код, но уже и не "человеческий". В этот момент происходит формирование блоков кода с разделением мест исполнения, только клиент, клиент/сервер, только сервер, web/thin-client, внешнее соединение.

При запуске конфигурации в режиме "Предприятие" (пользовательская работа) платформа считывает байт-код и докомпилирует его до машинного кода. При этом компиляция в машинный код происходт частично. Т.е только общие модули и модули, объектов которые сейчас нужны.